# Injecting DIV-Tag at top of page AND Automatic start of script when page is loading?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I started to program my own Chrome extension today and I'm stuck since hours with one problem.
Right now, I'm sending the current URL from the open website to my server where it's checked against some criterias and then a return value is sent back to the extension. This is working so far. I'm using only a popup.html, no background page.
The request is only sent when the user clicks on the icon in the browser.
How can I realize that the request is automatically sent, when the page is loaded?

If there is a specific return value from the server the user should be given an unannoying warning. Alert boxes and new windows are...well...annoying. Best way should be the little popup under the icon of the extension but that's not possible without a user's click. So I thought of a little -layer at the top of the page.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
window.addEventListener("load", sendRequest, false);  
function sendRequest() {
var q = "test";
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', 'http://www.testurl.com/check.php?q='+q, true); 
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById("textf").innerText = xmlHttp.responseText;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"<div style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color=blue;layer-background-color: blue;'><p>test </p><p>test2 </p></div>"});
}
  }
xmlHttp.send(null); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
//Just for the popup...
<font color="blue"><p id="textf">Checking...</p></font>
</body>
</html>
```

If I do

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"alert('testalert')"});
```

it gives me the alert. However, the  isn't working and I can't figure out why :(

Do I need a background page for all this since I only want to check the URL when the page is loaded?
Why is the -thing not working but the alert is?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` is for JavaScript only. To add content to a Web page, you must write JavaScript that manipulates the DOM. A good place for you to start learning this may be [Mozilla's DOM docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM). (DOM is a W3C standard and Chrome has implemented it, so yes, Mozilla pages are relevant here.)

If I may say so, it sounds like the best way forward for you is to scrap this and start over with a content script defined in your manifest so that Chrome will execute it for you; check [the Content Scripts documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to learn more. Since you're trying to accomplish your goal with no background page, and would therefore need to use XMLHttpRequest directly from your content script, you should add `"minimum_chrome_version": "13"` to your manifest, as Chrome 12 and earlier won't let you do that.

By the way, practically no one will understand what you're talking about when you use "-layer" and "-thing" like that. Please be more careful in making sure you are using proper terminology. Ask your peers if you're unsure of the proper term for something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used HTML-Tags which is not allowed here (didnt know that)...So there is missing "div" before "-layer" for example.